# Dating app - Which database structure do I need in Firebase Firestore to query all users except those who disliked me?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore, native

I'm creating a dating app with **React Native** and **Firebase Cloud Firestore**. In my app users can dislike other users to exclude them from the next query.

**Which database structure should I use to do the Firestore query**?

---

When you dislike someone, the userID will be stored in an array inside your user document. The Firestore query only provides 'array-contains' operator to filter based on array values. So I need to query "array-NOT-contains" but Firestore doesn't provide it.

---

***my Firestore Database structure***:

collection('user').doc('userID').match.dislike[*dislikedUserID1, dislikedUserID2,...*]

[screenshot: Firestore Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPx0B.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that `where` doesn't offer a clause like "array_does_not_contain".  Just do a less qualified query and subtract from the results.  This could be a wasteful query for someone who is widely disliked, but assuming most people are adorable...

```
const adorableMe = firebase.auth().currentUser
collection('user').where(/* they might think I'm a cutie pie */).get().then(snapshot => {
    // filter result to exclude the (tiny!) set of users who don't fancy me
    return snapshot.docs.filter(doc => !doc.data().dislikes.includes(adorableMe.id))
})
```

Comment: This query you propose, I have a question.
Let's say the collection "user" has 500 documents, and in the processing of the query (filter) I put a limit of 20 users to return.

How many ''read'' Firestore will charge in that particular operation?

The 500 of the total of the user collection or the 20 I actually need?

Comment: @carrasc0, I'm not super confident, but I think that limiting the the result set to 20 will get you charged for 20, not 500.  This isn't true for offsets, though.  See here...  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing

Comment: Yes, is confusing, because an often use case is to ''reference'' a big amount of documents in a collection, process it with a cursor and return a reasonable amount (20 for example). Something like your example above.
In the official doc I didn’t find yet an explanation for this case, unfortunately .

Comment: hey @carrasc0, did you ever find an answer to this question if firebase charges 500 of the total or the 20, I was wondering the same thing.

Comment: *firebaser here* If you limit the query to return (at most) 20 results, you will get charged for (at most) 20 document reads.